# Install Dell 1700n printer on WIn 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, printer

I have a new Dell XPS 13 and I want connect it to my ancient Dell 1700n ethernet printer.

I've tried these 3 things but none of them work.
https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=T6HJD

http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln69717/installing-1700-and-1700n-printer-drivers-kb-article-290221?lang=en

http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/dell-1700n/drivers

What can I do?

[image]

Comment: have you tried to install the drivers with *Run this program in compatibility mode for...*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ancient printer and getting it to work with new versions of Windows has been an issue going back to Win 7.  [Dell's latest driver is for Win 7](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/dell-1700n/drivers), and you could try compatibility mode.  So it appears that Dell is no longer actively supporting this printer.

However, the printer is equivalent to the Lexmark E332N (probably relabeled), which does have a Win10 driver.  Here are a couple of links:

- [Lexmark site](http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=driverSupport&locale=EN&userlocale=EN_US)
- [Third party site](https://www.driverguide.com/driver/download/Lexmark-E332n)

I'm not familiar with the third party site, but it looks like you might want to be vigilant about "free offers".  I included it only because the Lexmark site doesn't look very straightforward as far as which files you need.

Comment: progress. I download, install, and run the Lexmark IPSU utility. I get the the screen above (added to the original question)

Comment: @AlLelopath, I don't see anything added to the question.  But it looked like the Lexmark driver consisted of a whole collection of needed files, and you need to also match 32 vs. 64 bits with your Windows version.  If you downloaded just one file, the printer isn't likely to work.

Comment: Sorry, didn't edit the question correctly. Now it should be there

Comment: @AlLelopath, that one piece of the driver appears to just add it to the network.  You need the rest of the driver to print.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with getting Dell 1720dn to work on Win 10.
I downloaded a program called Driver Booster free from [www.majorgeeks.com](http://www.majorgeeks.com).
Found driver and installed. Printer working perfect

Comment: Hello! I'm not sure you noticed this, but this question was from 3 years ago.  You can totally answer, but just know you most likely won't get much reputation from it.  (nice answer btw!)

Comment: I did this and it got my 14yr old Dell 7520dn laser printer working on Win 10 Pro where Windows could not find a driver and the Dell Official Drivers site doesn't seem to have one that is compatible either. I will say however that `Driver Booster` puts a lot of junk gimmick programs on your computer.. about VPN software etc. Hopefully none are malware.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a couple Dell 1700s (USB connection only) that I've gotten working with Windows 10.   The user's first attempt at installing the printer leaves an unusable printer icon in their list of printers, so I start by removing that. Then I download the R147091.exe file from [Dell 1700/n Mono Laser Printer Drivers](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/dell-1700n/drivers)   to the user's computer, then right-click on the file to “Troubleshoot Compatibility” and run the installer.  As part of that install, the installer copies old Windows driver files into `c:\Dell`.

I plug the printer back in, Windows tries adding it again, when it asks for a printer driver I now say I “Have a Disc” and point it to the `.inf` file in `C:\Dell\printers\drivers\print\x64`.  On both attempts so far it has worked.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully completed installing my 2006 Dell 1710n on 3 Windows 10 64 bit OS's. I usually don't use the driver support sites, but I found this one to easy and successfull.

https://www.freeprinterdriverdownload.org/dell-1710n-driver-download-bw-laser-printer/

I downloaded the driver and installed it according to the readme.txt file and it worked flawlessly on 3 Windows 10 computers of various manufactures and ages.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem trying to keep a Dell 1700n alive. I'm sure I managed to get the Win7 driver to install once using Vista compatibility mode (I know that sounds weird). Anyway, on my latest 64-bit Windows 10 (HP laptop) I cannot get it to work.

So I went down the Lexmark route. As per the other answer, go to the [Lexmark site](http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=driverSupport&locale=EN&userlocale=EN_US). Select Lexmark E332N, Windows, 64-bit, English (or your language). Install both the IP Setup Utility, and the Universal Print Driver Installation Package. When the installer asks you to identify your printer, choose network, XL driver, supply the printer IP address, and make up a port name, e.g. Dell1700n. Printer will appear as Lexmark Universal V2 XL.

Working perfectly for me, and the dinosaur Dell lives on once again. Must be 15 years old. Apart from toner cartridges, and one change of print drum, the only glitch I've ever had was the paper feed deteriorating until it jammed constantly. Locate the feed roller with what looks like a rubber band. It goes glossy with age but turn it inside out and all perfect again.